# rewriting multiple functions in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using mouseover and mouseleave on different transparent  tags to swap a background image on my page. if I click on one of the  tags, the function is exited and the mouseover background image remains. on click also sets a div display to block, that was set to none in css. I have another click function that will set the background image to the original background image, as well as reset the div to display none. I know there is a more efficient way to do this then writing these two functions 14 times but I am not sure how...

```
$(document).ready(function() {



   $('.tips-number-14').on({
        mouseover: function(){
            $('.tips-numbers').css('backgroundImage','url(0-HTML-Resources/imgs/buying-a-car-2/tips-numbers-hover.png)'),
            $('.tips-number-14').css('backgroundImage','url(0-HTML-Resources/imgs/buying-a-car-2/tip-14-number.png)');
        },
        mouseleave: function(){
            $('.tips-numbers').css('backgroundImage','url(0-HTML-Resources/imgs/buying-a-car-2/tips-numbers.png)'),
            $('.tips-number-14').css('backgroundImage','none');
        },
        click: function(){
            $('.tip-14-info').css('display','block'),
            $('.tips-number-14').off('mouseleave');
        },
    });
    $('.close-info-14').on({
        click: function(){
            $('.tips-numbers').css('backgroundImage','url(0-HTML-Resources/imgs/buying-a-car-2/tips-numbers.png)'),
            $('.tip-14-info').css('display','none');
        },
    }); 


});
```

Comment: whether this structure is repeated... what you have now looks fine

Comment: if it is repeated then can you share the html sample

Comment: use data attributes to hold the id, than use that to build the selectors inside.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I complete follow your question. But it seems to me that you want to have the same handler for all '14' tags. You can try specifying all the tags in the selector (comma separated):

```
 $('.tips-number-14, .tips-number-13, .tips-number-12, ....').on({
       // your code here
       ... 
       ...
 });
```

You can also generate the selector string using a loop if the number of loops/elements keeps changing.

Do let me know if I misunderstood you.

Comment: I am using your method Vini, I have a different problem now. I click an a tag to leave my hover background image up, and show my div. when I click my close button, everything goes back to original as intended. but... when i mouseover an a tag again, then mouseleave, the hover background image stays up(does not change back to original background image). so essentially, it works fine once, then when I try again, the background hover image gets stuck.

Comment: Can you share a HTML sample. Maybe create a fiddle at jsfiddle.net and share the link.